# YII: Radiobuttons On Action Should Update The Text Field

Tags: php, yii

I want to create two buttons in `_form.php`.

The two buttons are `'0'=>approve` and `'1'=>Reject`.

Now, I have two text fields for `date` and `modified by`. I need to update `date` with the current date and `modify by` with the `login` name when `approve` is clicked and I need to update `date` with `null` and `modify by` with `login` name when reject is clicked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a `textfield` for `modifiedby` or `date`.

Check which button is pressed in controller. And do whatever action you want to take. Something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Post']['approve'])===true){
    $this->date = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
    $model->save();
}

if(isset($_POST['Post']['reject'])===true){
    $this->date = '';
    $model->save();
}
```

Adding this `rule` in the model, lets you add name on `insert` or `update`.

```
array('modifiedby','default','value'=>Yii::app()->user->title,'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
array('modifiedby','default','value'=>Yii::app()->user->title,'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert')
```